# Error: Cannot find module "./../providers/auth-service"

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to create Login/registered  in ionic 2 I get the error Cannot find module './../providers/auth-service/auth-service'. in the login.ts file. Please

i am new for ionic app and i am learning ionic framework 
so please help me

for the error

thise code in the file 
auth-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class User {
  name: string;
  email: string;

  constructor(name: string, email: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  currentUser: User;

  public login(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!
        let access = (credentials.password === "pass" && credentials.email === "email");
        this.currentUser = new User('Simon', 'saimon@devdactic.com');
        observer.next(access);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }

  public register(credentials) {
    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      // At this point store the credentials to your backend!
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }

  public getUserInfo() : User {
    return this.currentUser;
  }

  public logout() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.currentUser = null;
      observer.next(true);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

this code in the file login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthService } from '../providers/auth-service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  loading: Loading;
  registerCredentials = { email: '', password: '' };

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: AuthService, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

  public createAccount() {
    this.nav.push('RegisterPage');
  }

  public login() {
    this.showLoading()
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {        
        this.nav.setRoot('HomePage');
      } else {
        this.showError("Access Denied");
      }
    },
      error => {
        this.showError(error);
      });
  }

  showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...',
      dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }

  showError(text) {
    this.loading.dismiss();

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Fail',
      subTitle: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present(prompt);
  }
}
```

app structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgtRX.png)
Please help

Comment: next time please search for your title

Comment: What folders are `auth.service.ts` and `login.ts` located in?

Comment: app name ->src ->  pages -> 1 home 2login 3register 
app name -> src -> providers -> auth-service -> thane file (auth-service.ts)

Comment: please checked the image above in the question update please help

Comment: please help......